# ValueError - I can not load large language model falcon 7B in google colab

Tags: deep-learning, nlp, huggingface-transformers, huggingface, large-language-model

I am trying to run falcon 7B on google colab and i get the following error:

ValueError: Could not load model tiiuae/falcon-7b-instruct with any of the following classes: (<class 'transformers.models.auto.modeling_auto.AutoModelForCausalLM'>, <class 'transformers.models.auto.modeling_tf_auto.TFAutoModelForCausalLM'>).

¿Could you help me to solve this problem? Thank you for your time.

I am using this code extracted from [The Falcon has landed in the Hugging Face ecosystem](https://huggingface.co/blog/falcon):

```
from transformers import AutoTokenizer
import transformers
import torch

model = "tiiuae/falcon-7b-instruct"

tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(model)

pipeline = transformers.pipeline(
"text-generation",
model=model,
tokenizer=tokenizer,
torch_dtype=torch.bfloat16,
trust_remote_code=True,
device_map="auto",
)

sequences = pipeline(
"Write a poem about Valencia.",
max_length=200,
do_sample=True,
top_k=10,
num_return_sequences=1,
eos_token_id=tokenizer.eos_token_id,
)

for seq in sequences:
    print(f"Result: {seq['generated_text']}")
```

I have already tried re-installing Pytorch library.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem on colab and switching to a GPU instance(V100) worked for me. 
Here is a discussion board with the same problem:
https://huggingface.co/tiiuae/falcon-40b/discussions/3